# Pushsharp Compatible with Phonegap and Supported platforms + server control

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry, windows-phone-8, pushsharp

Is pushsarp compatible with phonegap all the supported platforms i need to support IOS , Android , BlackBerry and windows phone and second thing can i control the server side or sending the push notification control on my PHP server working with pushsharp or its not possible ????

Answer (score 1):

Pushsarp is server side library, so it's not related to phonegap. You can use anything you want on the server side to send the notifications.

To do push notification registration for the device, you can use phonegap plugins like https://github.com/bobeast/PushPlugin (which only supports APNS and GCM)

Answer (score 0):

Go down to the image on this page: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp
It clearly shows that it will only work for Android, iOS and Windows Phone. As for PhoneGap, it comes down to PhoneGap supporting push notifications, since PushSharp only sends them from a server and hvae no influence on how they are interpreted on the phone.